# Phonegap Installation

Tags: cordova, titanium

Hi I'm about to install phonegap on my MAC OSX 10.9
Before I have a Appcelerator Titanium installed on my machine then I removed it because of some reasons.

I have Node and NPM installed on my machine and I install phonegap using:

> > $ sudo npm install -g phonegap

then this is a weird thing after phonegap installed:

It creates a Titanium Studio folder in my Applications.
Please respond if you know how to fix this. I can't run phonegap on my machine.

> > npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
> >     npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
> >     /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/bin/phonegap -> /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
> >     phonegap@3.1.0-0.15.0 /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap

Comment: Do not post screenshot of your logs but copy&paste them, so we could read it.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm get prefix` will show the current `prefix` setting, which likely contains both the Titanium and phonegap directories.  `npm set prefix /usr/local/bin/phonegap` will likely fix this for you.

Answer (score -1):

After executing npm -g install phonegap 
Output:
200 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/bin/phonegap -> /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
phonegap@3.3.0-0.18.0 /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap

I have Titanium Studio (appcelerator) installed, and it uses node.js too.

After executing npm get prefix
/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local

which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm

After executing npm set prefix /usr/local/bin/phonegap nothing apparently happens but try again
npm get prefix and then

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/phonegap'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/phonegap'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/phonegap' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "get" "prefix"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Sweetcoder
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/phonegap
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/phonegap'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Sweetcoder/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
MacBook-Pro-de-Javier:~ Sweetcoder$ npm get prefix
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/phonegap'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/phonegap'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/phonegap' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "get" "prefix"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Sweetcoder
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/phonegap
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/phonegap'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Sweetcoder/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Then retry with sudo nom get prefix:
/usr/local/bin/phonegap

Install again phonegap:
now execute phonegap -bash: phonegap: command not found

Then cd /usr/local/bin/phonegap/bin and phonegap is there

Execute ./phonegap and the output is OK

The phonegap is not in the path

Then the problem is the prefix of de npm cause Titanium Studio installed. Remember the old prefix of npm get prefix
/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local

Set your prefix to /usr/local and try installing phonegap again

[NPM install -g not working after Titanium install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089016/npm-install-g-not-working-after-titanium-install)

Probably appears a message like  Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/phonegap not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap

Don't worry, exec /usr/local/bin/phonegap

and then you will see you can execute phonegap command

If I have problems with Titanium updates I will edit this post