# NPM install -g not working after Titanium install

Tags: titanium, npm

I have installed Titanium onto my mac and now when ever I try to globally install any npm packages it fails.

The output from my install is

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loggly
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/timespan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/timespan
/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/share/npm/bin/grunt-init -> /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt-init/bin/grunt-init
grunt-init@0.2.1 /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt-init
├── semver@1.0.14
├── colors@0.6.2
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt@0.4.1 (which@1.0.5, dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3, eventemitter2@0.4.13, async@0.1.22, lodash@0.9.2, coffee-script@1.3.3, underscore.string@2.2.1, findup-sync@0.1.2, iconv-lite@0.2.11, nopt@1.0.10, rimraf@2.0.3, minimatch@0.2.12, glob@3.1.21, js-yaml@2.0.5)
└── prompt@0.1.12 (async@0.1.22, pkginfo@0.3.0, winston@0.5.11)
```

When I then subsequently do which grunt-init, nothing is returned. It seems like something which is part of Titanium is interfering with my -g npm install?

This only started happening since I installed Titanium. I can get it working if I manually install grunt-init in the npm directory, but this has literally taken away the best feature for me.

please help!

Comment: after uninstalling npm, I reinstalled it and still got an issue. looking at the npm log 

error Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/share/npm/lib'
4 error  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/share/npm/lib']
4 error   errno: 3,
4 error   code: 'EACCES',
4 error   path: '/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/share/npm/lib' }
5 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: something is still left in there>!?

Comment: Fixed it

Ended up completely removing node and npm, then re-installing using nvm.

It seems like some permissions issue occurred in the past and hence screwed all my subsequent installs after Titanium.

Word of advice nvm seems to be the way forward!

Answer (score 20):

Try typing:

```
npm set prefix /usr/local
```

Then installing again.

Comment: In my case I used ``npm set prefix /usr/local/share/npm`` and worked as well